# Angular Form Validation working opposite of how it should actually work

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-forms, form-control

ts file:

```typescript
myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    Id: new FormControl("",[Validators.pattern('^.{1,50}$')])
});
    
addEntry(){
    this.finalmsg =[];
    let class = '';
    let msg = '';
    let snackbar = new SnackbarComponent(this.snackbar);
    if(this.myForm.controls['Id'].invalid){
        msg = 'Enter between 1 to 50';
        class = 'redsnackbar';
        this.finalmsg.push(msg);
        snackbar.openSnackBar(this.finalmsg, "Close", class);
    }
    this.dialogRef.close("OK")
}
```

This is the code I am using to validate the input field. It works opposite of how it should If I change from invalid to valid then the snackbar is displayed. And when its invalid, then it does not go in the loop the dialog is closed. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Expression you used is what causes the problem , replace the Regex to the following :

```
myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
   //YOU SHOULD TELL THE `Validators` TO only allow digit from 0 to 50 and no 
   //other character should be allowed
    Id: new FormControl("",[Validators.pattern('^[1-9]$|^[1-9][0-9]$|^(50)$')])
});
    
addEntry(){
    this.finalmsg =[];
    let class = '';
    let msg = '';
    let snackbar = new SnackbarComponent(this.snackbar);
    if(this.myForm.controls['Id'].invalid){
        msg = 'Enter between 1 to 50';
        class = 'redsnackbar';
        this.finalmsg.push(msg);
        snackbar.openSnackBar(this.finalmsg, "Close", class);
    }
    this.dialogRef.close("OK")
}
```

Enjoy

Comment: Still same issue..